# Move file in Nodejs if file exists otherwise create file

Tags: node.js, fs, es6-promise

I am trying to move a file from a location `abc` to location `xyz` if the file already exists in location `xyz` delete it then save the new one.

Here is my code

```
const promises = {
  deleteFile: path => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fs = require('fs');

      fs.stat(path, (err, stat) => {
        if (err === null) {

          fs.unlink(path, err => {
            if (err) { return reject(err) }
            resolve();
          })
        } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
          console.log('File does not exist');
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  copyFile: (from, to) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
      copyFile(from, to, (err) => {
        if (err) { return reject(err); }
        console.log(`Finished writing file ${to}`);
        resolve();
      })
    })
  }
}

const copyFile = (from, to, overallCb) => {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const rs = fs.createReadStream(from)
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(to)

    let cbCalled = false;
    function done (err) {
      overallCb(err);
      cbCalled = true;
    }

    rs.on('error', (err) => {
      done(err);
    })

    ws.on('error', (err) => {
      done(err);
    })
    rs.pipe(ws);
  }
;

const OUTPUT_PATH   = `./js/libs/`
  , _NODE_MODULES   = './node_modules/'
  , filePath = `${_NODE_MODULES}somePathToAFile`
  ;

promises.deleteFile(`${OUTPUT_PATH}someFile.min.js`)
  .then(promises.copyFile(filePath, `${OUTPUT_PATH}someFile.min.js`))
  .then(words => {
    console.log('**** done doing things ****');
  })
  .catch(error => { console.log(`ERROR`, error); })
```

If the file exists it just simply deletes the file and does nothing else.

If the file DOES NOT exist everything works fine.

Any idea on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had some promise errors in my code... For future me here is the working version of the above code

```
'use strict';

const promises = {
  deleteFile: path => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fs = require('fs');

      fs.stat(path, (err, stat) => {
        if (err === null) {

          fs.unlink(path, err => {
            if (err) { return reject(err) }
            resolve(`Removing document at ${path}`);
          })
        } else if(err.code === 'ENOENT') {
          resolve('File does not exist');
        } else {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  copyFile: (from, to) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      copyFile(from, to, (err) => {
        if (err) { return reject(err); }
        resolve(`Finished writing file ${to}`);
      })
    })
  }
}

const copyFile = (from, to, overallCb) => {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const rs = fs.createReadStream(from)
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(to)

    let cbCalled = false;
    function done (err) {
      overallCb(err);
      cbCalled = true;
    }

    rs.on('error', done)
    ws.on('error', done)
      .on('close', done)

    rs.pipe(ws);
  }
;

const OUTPUT_PATH   = './js/libs/'
  , _NODE_MODULES   = './node_modules/'
  , filePath        = `${_NODE_MODULES}somePathToAFile`
  ;


promises.deleteFile(`${OUTPUT_PATH}someFile.min.js`)
 .then(msg => {
   console.log(msg)
   return promises.copyFile(filePath, `${OUTPUT_PATH}someFile.js`)
 })
 .then(msg => {
   console.log(msg)
 })
 .catch(err => { // Do errory things}
```